# Replacing the value of one form field with another

Tags: django

I have written a piece of code where the user can select an occupation from a select box (teacher, doctor, pilot, etc) and if their occupation isn't in the list they can select 'other' then write their occupation in a textbox underneath.

I can successfully detect if they selected 'other' from the dropdown box, but cannot figure out how to populate the 'occupation' field with the data from the 'other' field.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OccupationForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.occupation)
        if form.is_valid():
            # if user selected 'other' - get input from text field
            if form['occupation'].value() == 'other':
                # this doesnt work
                #form_data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
                #form.other = form_data.get('other', '')
                #form.save()
                return redirect('#')

            #form.save()
            #return redirect('#')

    else:
        form = OccupationForm(instance=request.user.occupation)
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
shortened models.py

```
class Occupation(models.Model):
    # I just realized, maybe this should be OneToManyField ??
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    OCCUPATIONS = (
        ('teacher', 'Teacher'),
        ('doctor', 'Doctor'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    )

    occupation = models.CharField('What is your job?', max_length=200, null=True, choices=OCCUPATIONS)
```

shortened forms.py

```
class OccupationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    other = forms.CharField(required=False, label='')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('occupations') == 'other':
            cleaned_data['occupations'] = cleaned_data.get('other')
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Occupations

        fields = ['occupations']
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [clean methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) of your form is the place where you validate and clean data sent to the form, this includes potentially changing the data.

```
class OccupationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ....

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('occupation') == 'other':
            cleaned_data['occupation'] = cleaned_data.get('other')
        return cleaned_data
```

Now you can just call `form.save` straight after `form.is_valid` as the `clean` method will have cleaned/returned the correct data

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to work, however I'm now getting a warning "Select a valid choice. INPUT is not one of the available choices." on my form (not an error). I thought that wouldn't be the case as it's being saved as a CharField rather than a ChoiceField.

ps - I've recently began learning to code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can add the model and form to your question if you want help with that. I'm going to guess that the model field has choices?

Comment: I edited my original post and added them. Thank you

Comment: The `occupation` field has choices, if you set it to anything other than one of the choices then the model will not validate

Comment: Oh ok. Is there another field type which i could use which woild allow me to offer a range of choices as well as a user input field if none are suitable?

Comment: You could remove choices from the model field and move it to the form?